# Blender Won't Open because it says I need OpenGL 3.3

Tags: opengl

I've recently wanted to get back into using blender for some fun art projects, but anytime I try and install the program and run it, I run into issues.  The last time I used it was in December of 2020, so I know it's updated, but I'm pretty sure my computer specs should be good enough to run the program..  I'm not sure what's going on...

I've tried updating my graphics card drivers (they're up to date), I've uninstalled and reinstalled them just to be sure.  I've found an opengl32.dll file and moved it into the blender folder, and it opened the program, but ran terribly slow (very glitchy and would eventually not respond when I click different shading views), I uninstalled it and reinstalled it and now adding that file doesn't even let it open.  I've tried installing an older version (the version I was working on before, and that doesn't work either.  I'm not sure what to do next....  I've added photos of what is popping up, and my computer specs.  I also don't know if it would affect it, but I have a Cintiq 13 attached..

Any help is appreciated, I just really want to get back in the program and make things :/

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please show me the version of windows you are using? Go to the Windows menu, type run, and hit enter. It will open the run menu. Type "winver", and press enter. This will show me your Windows version, so I can better assist you. Just send me a screenshot of it.

Comment: There is an option inside the Nvidia control panel in which you can select a program (Blender in this case) and then in one of the option that says something about Openg GL, you need to be sure that the Nvidia GPU is selected. I don't have windows at the moment, so i can show you this option directly

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and I appreciate you reaching out!  I figured it out, my windows was having issues updating, and just needed to be updated!